# set text to TextView on action button of AlerView click [iOS, Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I've created `UIAlertController` with Three action buttons, now I want to set text to a `TextView` on each button.
Problem is this that when I click a button then result of previously clicked button is printed on `TextView`.

> My Code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mTextView.text = ""
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func showDialogOnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //Creating UIAlert, giving its title and message, setting style(alert OR alertSheet)
        let mDialog = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "This is the message" , preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        //add actions/buttons to alert
        mDialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(action) in
            print("Cancel")
            self.mTextView.text = "Cancel"
        }))
        mDialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Default", style: .default, handler: {(action) in
            print("Default")
            self.mTextView.text = "Default"
        }))
        mDialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Destructive", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) in
            print("Destructive")
            self.mTextView.text = "Destructive"
        }))

        self.present(mDialog, animated: true)

    }

}
```

Comment: There isn't actually any `UIAlertView`... it's been deprecated a long time ago. You're using `UIAlertController`

Comment: Are you getting logs like Cancel, Default or Destructive?

Comment: I'm beginner in iOS, can you edit my code please?

Comment: if you click the particular button you get the logs for each button Cancel, Default or Destructive

Comment: in log correct text is displaying, for example I click Cancel there is displayed cancel.
1) First I click Cancel
    Nothing on TextView
2) Second I click Default
    Cancel is displayed on TextView
3) Third I click Destructive
    Default is displayed in TextView

Comment: Can’t reproduce any problem with the program. Are you running in the simulator on an old computer? Maybe your simulator is misbehaving. Try running on a device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i think can be possible issue is you are testing this in your Simulator and your computer is having low graphic configuration same thing happens with be when i test my code in my old mac mini.You can do two things :-

1. Test the code in a physical device
2. Try to minimize your app in your simulator and come back to the app you'll see the effect Or change the view back and forth to see the effect.

Let me know if I was right.